# Dynamic select box in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to create a select box that goes from 1 to a number defined in a active record. This number will change.

So far I know I can create a select box like this:

```
<%= f.select  :numbers, %w[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ] %>
```

but what I need is something like this:

```
<%= f.select  :numbers, %w[1..@user.number] %>
```

is there a way to create a nice dynamic select box in rails or do I need to manually create select tags in html with a for loop or something like that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn a [Range](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Range.html) into an Array using the `to_a` method:

```
<%= f.select :numbers, (1 .. @user.number).to_a %>
```

Or you can hand `f.select` the raw range and it will call `to_a` for you:

```
<%= f.select :numbers, 1 .. @user.number %>
```

From the [fine manual](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select):

> **select**(object, method, choices, options = {}, html_options = {})
>
> Create a select tag and a series of contained option tags for the provided object and method. The option currently held by the object will be selected, provided that the object is available.
>
> There are two possible formats for the choices parameter, corresponding to other helpers’ output:
>
> - A flat collection: see `options_for_select`
> - A nested collection: see `grouped_options_for_select`

And [`options_for_select` says](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select):

> **options_for_select**(container, selected = nil)
>
> Accepts a container (hash, array, enumerable, your type) and returns a string of option tags.

A Range is an Enumerable so both `f.select` calls above should yield the same result.